# r raster can't get if else logic to work with variable that is a constant

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to do some conditional logic on my raster brick. In the code below `myFun1` correctly generates `raster.out1`. But `myFun2` generates an error when trying to produce `raster.out2`. The error message is

> Error in which(test) : argument to 'which' is not logical

Other than the use of a variable with the value of 5, these two functions look identical. I'm missing something clearly.

```
library(raster)
raster.in <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
raster.in[] <- runif(ncell(raster.in), min = -10, max = 10)

const1 <- 5

myFun1 <- function(x, ...) { 
  ifelse(x <= 5, 5, x  )
}

raster.out1 <- calc(raster.in, fun = myFun1)

myFun2 <- function(x, tbase, ...) { 
  ifelse(x <= tbase, tbase, raster.in)
}
raster.out2 <- calc(raster.in, fun = myFun2(x = raster.in, tbase = const1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, you should have `x` instead of `raster.in` in your function, and to put a function w multiple parameters you need some extra code:

```
myFun2 <- function(x, tbase, ...) { 
  ifelse(x <= tbase, tbase, x)
}


calc(raster.in, function(x){myFun2(x, tbase = const1)})
```

Answer (score 2):

astrofunkswag's answer is correct but there are more direct ways to get what you want with `clamp` or `reclassify`

```
r1 <- clamp(raster.in, const1)

r2 <- reclassify(raster.in, cbind(-Inf, const1, const1))
```

There is also a hidden (and less efficient) ifel method

```
r3 <- raster:::.ifel(raster.in < const1, const1, raster.in)
```

Comment: Offtopic comment, but Robert, when should we switch from raster to your new package terra?

Comment: I cannot give a precise answer, but work is needed to complete functionality and get rid of bugs. My guess is that by August it should be reasonable to replace taster with terra.  Of course it is helpful if you start early, particularly with the development version on github, and provide feedback.

Comment: clamp is exactly what I needed. But, ... it is hitting on my hard drive like cray while I have 6gb ram free according to my activity monitor. I sometimes use readAll on my mac because it seems to do math operations faster. Doesn't work so well on my new line box. Any hidden methods to encourage clamp to take better advantage of RAM, either in raster or terra?

Comment: See `rasterOptions`  chunksize, maxmemory, memfrac

Comment: Here's the output of a test I did.

Comment: > starttime <- Sys.time()
      > tmin_clamped <- clamp(tmin, lower = Tbase_barley, upper =  Tbase_max_barley, useValues = TRUE)
      > endtime <- Sys.time()
      > endtime - starttime
      Time difference of 1.454485 hours
      > 
      > rasterOptions(chunksize = 1e+09, maxmemory = 6e+09)
> 
      > starttime <- Sys.time()
      > tmin_clamped <- clamp(tmin, lower = Tbase_barley, upper =       Tbase_max_barley, useValues = TRUE)
      > endtime <- Sys.time()
> endtime - starttime
      Time difference of 14.07269 mins`

Comment: I don't know how to format the output properly. But the bottom line is that changing the chunksize to 1e+09 and maxmemory to 6e+09 reduced the time to run a specific line of code with clamp from 1.54 hours to 14 minutes.

Comment: Thanks that is very useful. I will change the defaults to make them a bit less conservative.

Comment: Might be useful to do machine-specific defaults; that is, find out what the ram size is, or maybe free ram; do the same. I'm guessing that the current defaults were set for 8 gb ram machines. I'm also guessing that you'll have lots of people with between 16 and 64 gb of ram running raster.

Comment: There already is a ceiling based on available RAM. See `canProcessInMemory(raster(), verbose=T)`  and  `memfrac` should perhaps be the only user  rasterOption.